# Generate 8 unique random numbers from 0 to 7

Tags: c++, algorithm, random

I'm making a simple script that generates 8 random values from 0 to 7 and stores them into an array named `random_numbers`.

This is my try:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int random_numbers[8];
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        random_numbers[i] = 1+ rand() % 8;
        cout << random_numbers[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me repeated values. I would like to have `random_numbers` filled of random values from 0 to 7, but without any repeated numbers.

How can I do that?

Comment: You'll have to do the deduplication manually - after every new number check the number doesn't yet exist and regenerate if it does. There are some neat tricks you can do to reduce the chances of needing to re-roll but it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: ... and it looks like your code generates 1-8 not 0-7. If you want 0-7 you should remove the `1 +` before `rand() % 8`.

Comment: Unrelated: Did you consider using `std::vector` instead of `int[]`?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Why would he do that? he doesn’t need dynamic allocation. Maybe use `std::array`.

Comment: @qdii There is no law that C arrays are forbidden, I was merely suggesting to consider `std::vector`. Neither am I opposed to `std::array`.

Comment: Again, why use a vector when you know the size beforehand? Might as well suggest using an `std::map<int,int>`.

Comment: Because premature optimisation is bad.

Comment: You don't want random numbers at all here. You want the numbers 0 to 7, in random order. std::shuffle is certainly the easy way to go. If you want to do it yourself, Google "Fisher-Yates Shuffle".

Comment: @Rhymoid Even though I doubt it is *premature optimization* to choose the data structure best fit to the problem first, I agree with you on the general idea and I suggest using `typedef std::array<int,8> container` to be able to swap between container type in case the problem's needs change.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generate the numbers 0 through 7, then shuffle them. Assuming this is actually C++, not C (because of the `cout`), use `std::random_shuffle`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[8] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    std::srand(unsigned(std::time(0)));

    std::random_shuffle(a, a + 8);

    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        std::cout << a[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Be warned: [cppreference.com states](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) that "The random number generator is implementation-defined, but the function `std::rand` is often used." I've seeded that with `std::srand`, but apparently that's not completely portable.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: probably a mistake given the `cout`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class Random {
public:
    Random(){
        srand( static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
    }

    unsigned int operator()(unsigned int max){
        double tmp = static_cast<double>( rand() ) / static_cast<double>( RAND_MAX );
        return static_cast<unsigned int>( tmp * max );
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int random_numbers[8];
    int size = sizeof(random_numbers)/sizeof(int); 
    for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
        random_numbers[i]=i;
    Random r;
    random_shuffle(random_numbers, random_numbers + size, r);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << random_numbers[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks BLUEPIXY. But why I'm always getting the same exit in every execution, which is `7  3  1  4  5  2  6  0` ?

Comment: @Borja: you still have to call `srand`, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using c++ any way I modified you code a bit more. Use vector instead of array, this should make your life easier, and this generates 0-7 in a random order without duplicates:

compile with `-std=c++0x`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<int> random_numbers(8);
    iota(random_numbers.begin(), random_numbers.end(), 1);

    random_shuffle(random_numbers.begin(), random_numbers.end());
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < random_numbers.size(); i++) {
        cout << random_numbers[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to get fancy, you might as well use [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).

Comment: Why would you use vector when you don't need dynamic size?

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
int random_numbers[8];

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                random_numbers[i] =getRand(i);
                cout << random_numbers[i] << endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
int getRand(int entries)
{
    int flag = 0;
    int randno ;
    randno = rand() % 8;
    for(int i=0;i<entries;i++)
    {

        if( random_numbers[i]==randno)
        {
           randno = rand() % 8;
           continue;
        }
    }
    return randno;

}
```

Comment: But it has O(N²) complexity while the problem can be solved in linear time using the standard library. In other words, it's a [Schlemiel the Painter algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

Comment: I think you mean `< entries` not `<= entries` else you'll compare against the current uninitialised (0 here) cell. Which will mean you can't ever generate zero?

Comment: @Rup ya Right . I will change that