# How to use random_shuffle in a for loop to achieve different different shuffled arrays?

Tags: c, random

i want to have 10 different shuffled form of an array...but random_shuffle produce the same sequence for 10 times...
        and my code is...

```
for(k=0;k<10;k++) {
    for (l=0; l<SIZE;l++)
        a[l]=l+1;

    srand(time(0));
    random_shuffle(a,a+SIZE);  //getting the  shuffled sequence

    for(;i<10;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
            rcusseq[i][j]=a[m++]; //storing the sequence in a 2d array
            printf("%d\t",rcusseq[i][j]);
        }
        m=0;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
    5       4       2       1       3
    5       4       2       1       3
    5       4       2       1       3
    5       4       2       1       3
    5       4       2       1       3
    5       4       2       1       3
    5       4       2       1       3
    5       4       2       1       3
    5       4       2       1       3
    5       4       2       1       3
```

Press any key to continue

Comment: use `srand` before, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833676/generate-8-random-numbers-and-store-them-in-a-array-c

Comment: So your real question is: how do I actually produce random numbers?

Comment: You don't need or want to `srand` inside a loop, or indeed more than once in the program.

Answer (score 3):

You're reinitializing the random number generator each time, as your code is quick enough to run within 1 second, you get the same seed every  time.

Move `srand(time(0));`out of the loop.

Only call srand() once in a program, e.g. at the beginning of main().

Comment: thank you...i found my mistake it was a silly logical mistake.the last generated sequence was stored in every indices of the 2d array that was my mistake.calling randomshuffle inside the outer for loop brought correct answer for(;i<10;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
            rcusseq[i][j]=a[m++]; //storing the sequence in a 2d array
            printf("%d\t",rcusseq[i][j]);
        }
        m=0;
        printf("\n");
    }